# the pointer passing returns unexpected error

Tags: c, pointers

i am using atmega16 to make a simple example

```
void uartrecieve(unsigned char * data1)
{
    data1="on";

}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned char *z;
    DDRC=0xFF;
    uartinit();
    while(1)
    {
        uartrecieve(z);

        if(strcmp(z,"on")==0)
        {
            PORTC =0xff;
            _delay_ms(6000);
        }   
        else
        {
            PORTC=0x03;
        _delay_ms(6000);
        }
   }

}
```

my question is this ... why does it always print 0x03 ... aren't the 2 values supposed to be equal and therefore it should print 0xFF on PORTC!???

Answer (score 3):

You are not updating the actual string pointer.

The following code will do what you want :

```
void uartrecieve(unsigned char ** data1)
{
    *data1 = "on";
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned char *z;
    DDRC=0xFF;
    uartinit();
    while(1)
    {
        uartrecieve(&z);

        if(strcmp(z,"on")==0)
        {
            PORTC =0xff;
            _delay_ms(6000);
        }
        else
        {
            PORTC=0x03;
            _delay_ms(6000);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need the interface to be in this format [ void uartrecieve(unsigned char * data1) ] so how can i do it!?

Comment: You have to copy the string then.

Comment: sorry but can you show it to me in code!? i am sorry but i am new here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't just assign a value to a `char *` to copy a string, you have to use `strcpy` or `memcpy`. But then your problem is that you didn't allocate memory for the copied string, so you need to do that too.

In the example I allocated 256 byte, which should be enough if you want to receive some real things over uart I think? Else you need to enlarge it either dynamically or static. Or you could read it in chunks.

```
#define UARTBUFFERSIZE 256

void uartrecieve(unsigned char * data1)
{
    /* Copy a maximum of 255 byte + 1 zero byte*/
    strncpy(data1, "on", UARTBUFFERSIZE -1);
    /* Make sure it's zero terminated */
    data1[UARTBUFFERSIZE -1] = 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned char z[UARTBUFFERSIZE];
    DDRC=0xFF;
    uartinit();
    while(1)
    {
        uartrecieve(z);
        if(strcmp(z,"on")==0)
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry but can you show it to me in code!? i am sorry but i am new here :)

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope I didn't make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
void uartrecieve(unsigned char **data1)
{
    *data1="on";
}
```

and call it thus:

```
uartrecieve(&z);
```

Alternatively, you can do as [Juri Robl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276473/juri-robl) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21583775/15168).

Comment: thanks but i need the interface to be in this format [ void uartrecieve(unsigned char * data1) ] so how can i do it!?

Comment: Then you do it the way Juri Robl suggested; allocate space in your calling code, and use `strcpy()` in the `uartreceive()`, making sure you have enough space allocated for the message that needs to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Let `uartrecieve()` fill an array that already has allocated space.

```
void uartrecieve(unsigned char *data1, size_t n) {
  strncpy(data1, "on", n);
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned char z[80];
  ...
  {
    uartrecieve(z, sizeof z);
    if(strcmp(z,"on")==0) 
    ...
```